# Chrome Dev Tools Un-responsive Source Tabs

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

This problem has started happening in the last week.

The dev tools background changes to a pale orange, and a yellow warning sign appears on the currently selected source page tab.

I am unable to select between source tabs, unable to use the mouse wheel to scroll through the CSS, and as I type CSS quite fast, I usually lose one or two lines of CSS everytime the page background goes orange.

It's really starting to bug me now!

[image]

The only thing that fixes it is to to close the browser and start again, but this only lasts a few minutes until it happens again. Up until 2 weeks ago, this never happened.

Is this normal? Has this happened to anyone else?

Version 33.0.1750.146 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new update, the update is 33.0.1750.149 m. May be worth giving a go!

Visit `chrome://chrome/` to look for the update

Comment: Yeah I thought I had the latest version, but just checked and there was an update. Installed update, and the screen still goes orange, but at least now the tabs are clickable, and the mouse scroll works! Guess I can live with that!

Comment: Strange that you have been having issues, have you tried to reset Chrome to default? That potentially could sort it out too. I have been using the Dev tools with no issues on Windows 7 & 8...

Comment: Just reset all settings, its seems to be as i type over 5 or 6 lines of CSS the orange background appears. Now that I can actually click the tabs, when I hover over it, it says "changes to this file were not saved to file system". I wouldn't want to save to a file system anyway, because I'm not working on a local environment. Anyway, the update sorted half of my issues! :-P